# Enable/Disable Button Based On Empty TextBoxes Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

validating the button with one field works with this code.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function SetButtonStatus(sender, target)
{
if ( sender.value.length >= 12 )
document.getElementById(target).disabled = false;
else
document.getElementById(target).disabled = true;
}
script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this, 'btnButton')">asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled="false" />


<asp:TextBox ID="SECONDtxtText" runat="server" />
```

but i need to check on two fields. i tried with if else if else, but didn't work.
How can i add the extra field to check thanks.

Comment: The language attribute is deprecated. Change document.getElementById(target).disabled = false; to document.getElementById(target).disabled = ""; and document.getElementById(target).disabled = true; to document.getElementById(target).disabled = "disabled";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function SetButtonStatus()
{
var fv=document.getElementById('<%=txtText.ClientID%>').value;
var sv=document.getElementById('<%=SECONDtxtText.ClientID%>').value;
//Change these conditions as your requirement
if ( fv.length >= 12 && sv.length>=12)
document.getElementById('<%=btnButton.ClientID%>').disabled = false;
else
document.getElementById('<%=btnButton.ClientID%>').disabled = true;
}
script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus()">asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled="false" />


<asp:TextBox ID="SECONDtxtText" runat="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus()" />
```

Comment: thank you malkam. I just had to replace <%=btnButton.ClientID%> with ID's and worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: skip the clever arguments in `onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this, 'btnButton')">`, instead just `onkeyup="SetButtonStatus()">`.

```
function SetButtonStatus(){
    document.getElementById('btnButton').disabled =
        document.getElementById('txtText').value.length < 12 ||
        document.getElementById('SECONDtxtText').value.length < 12;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your html with errors

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <script>
        function SetButtonStatus(sender, target)
        {
            if ( sender.value.length >= 12 )
                document.getElementById(target).disabled = false;
            else
                document.getElementById(target).disabled = true;
        }
        </script>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this, 'btnButton')"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled="false" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="SECONDtxtText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateInput() {
var txt=document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
pass = true;
for (var i=0; i<txt.length;i++) {
if (txt[i].value =="") {
pass = false;
} 
}
document.getElementById("myButton").disabled=!pass?true:false;
document.getElementById("myButton").value=!pass?(passICount+passTCount) + 
"Submit":"Submit";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="validateInput()" onmousedown="validateInput()" 
onkeyup="validateInput()">
<form onsubmit="">
<textarea name="myInput"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this answer better than the ones already there?  If your answer does not provide some different way of doing it (and you explain why or how), it is not useful.